# Fourier transform of a time-derivative signal post-operated by an exponential

Tags: fourier-analysis, control-theory

Is the Fourier transform of $e^{-at}\dot{x}(t)$ for $a>0$ given by $j\omega X(a+j\omega)$ where $X(j\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of $x(t)$? Can somebody please show me the steps how to derive it without using the shortcuts.

Comment: Hi, welcome.  It seems like this should be a pretty straightforward integration problem.  What did you get when you tried that?

Comment: Actually, I am getting confused with the steps. Sometimes it seems that the answer should be $(a+j\omega)X(a+j\omega)$

Comment: If you would write out your steps, the community might be able to unconfuse you.

Answer (score 0):

By the Convolution theorem, we have that the Fourier Transform of a product is given by the convolution of their Fourier Transforms:

$$\mathcal{F}[f(t)g(t)](\omega) = \sqrt{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathcal{F}[f(t)](s -\omega)\mathcal{F}[g(t)](s)\, ds$$

The Fourier Transform of $e^{-at}$ is given by

\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}[e^{-at}](\omega) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(a+i\omega)t}\, dt\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i(\omega - ia)t}\,dt\\
&= \sqrt{2\pi}\,\delta(\omega-ia)
\end{align}

The Fourier Transform of $\dot x(t)$ can be obtained using integration by parts:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}[\dot x(t)](\omega) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dot x(t)e^{-i\omega t}\,dt\\
&= \frac{-i\omega}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t) e^{-i\omega t}\,dt\\
&= -i\omega\mathcal{F}[x(t)](\omega) =: -i\omega\xi(\omega)
\end{align}

Plugging these results into the convolution integral from above, we have

\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}\left[e^{-at}\dot x(t)\right](\omega) &= -2\pi i\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(s - (\omega + ia))\, s\,\xi(s)\\
&= - 2\pi i\left(\omega + ia\right)\xi(\omega + ia)
\end{align}

As you can see, aside from some factors of $-2\pi$, which can be down to convention, your second result is nearly the correct one - you're just missing an $i$ in there as well.

Comment: Thanks #Tom. Could you pls add some more detailed derivation of the last part?

Comment: Hi #Tom, could you pls check further that $\mathcal{F}[\dot{x}(t)] $ must be $i \omega X(i\omega)$ but not $-i\omega X(i\omega) $. And in the last expression, I feel the extra $i $ won't appear.

Comment: @ParijatBhowmick The negative sign is convention. If the Fourier Transform is done with $e^{i\omega t}$ instead of $e^{-i\omega t}$, then it does not appear. The $2\pi$ is convention as well, as there are different definitions that include different factors of $2\pi$ in the Fourier Transform.

Comment: @ParijatBhowmick What part would you like further elaboration on? Also, why do you feel that the $i$ does not appear? Have you spotted an error in my calculations?

Comment: I guess $\mathcal{F}[\dot{x}(t)]=i\omega \xi(i\omega)$ and in the last part, this $i\omega$ has been replaced by the dummy variable $s$. Could you pls include the in-between steps of the last integration?

Comment: According to general convention, in the final answer, $\xi(a+i \omega)$ should appear instead of $\xi(i a+\omega)$ since $a$ is the real part. As multiplying by $e^{-at}$ means shifting the ROC line from $i\omega$ axis to $a + i\omega$ axis.

Comment: Hi #Tom, the Delta function wouldn't work in the present case as it contains an extra $i$-operator in its argument. $\delta(\cdot)$ function can contain only pure angular frequency terms without having any $i$-operator associated with them, e.g. $\delta(j(\omega-\omega_{0}))$.

Answer (score 0):

I provide the following as an alternative that sticks a little more closely to your original notation.

Let
$$y\left( t \right) = {e^{ - at}}\dot x\left( t \right){\rm{   }}a > 0$$
Since
$$X\left( {j\omega } \right) = \int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {dt\,{e^{ - j\omega t}}} x\left( t \right){\rm{   }} \Rightarrow {\rm{   }}X\left( {j\omega  + a} \right) = \int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {dt\,{e^{ - \left( {j\omega  + a} \right)t}}x\left( t \right)}$$
using integration by parts
$$\begin{array}{c}
Y\left( {j\omega } \right) = \int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {dt\,{e^{ - j\omega t}}} y\left( t \right) = \int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {dt\,{e^{ - \left( {j\omega  + a} \right)t}}\dot x\left( t \right)} \\
 =  - \left( {j\omega  + a} \right)\left. {{e^{ - \left( {j\omega  + a} \right)t}}x\left( t \right)} \right|_{ - \infty }^\infty  + \left( {j\omega  + a} \right)\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {dt\,{e^{ - \left( {j\omega  + a} \right)t}}x\left( t \right)} \\
 = \left( {j\omega  + a} \right)X\left( {j\omega  + a} \right)
\end{array}$$
This derivation assumes both Fourier Transforms actually exist and that the endpoints in the integration by parts vanish.  As far as I can tell, this is equivalent to the previous answer, other than the normalization assumed and the integration by parts, where I think an additional minus sign got added.

Comment: Thanks #John. I guess this will work fine even if $\dot{x}(t)$ is an unbounded signal as because $e^{-at}\dot{x}(t)$ remains bounded. The same trick applies here which is used to obtain Laplace transform instead of Fourier transform for signals, which are not bounded on the $j\omega$ axis. That means shifting the ROC (region of convergence) from $j\omega$ axis to $a+j\omega$ axis so that the transform exists.

Comment: Note that as t approaches negative infinity, x(t) must vanish quickly enough to overcome the effect of the exponential.

Comment: Thanks #John. For causal signals, $x(t)=0$ for $\forall t < 0$ and as $t \rightarrow +\infty$, dut to the effect of the exponential term $e^{-at}$, the product $e^{-at} \dot{x}(t) \rightarrow 0$ even if $\dot{x}(t)$ is not bounded.

Comment: Agreed, but problem did not formally state x(t) is causal..  Also, there are some x(t) which can overwhelm even the negative exponential.  I mention these two only because this is a math web site, and in math one should worry about these secondary details.